# fread specifying separator within column

Tags: r, dataset

I am trying to parse a 2 column list that is separated using multiple spaces for columns and single spaces for words within a column. Nothing I have tried has successfully split the data into two columns. How do I do this?

```
library(data.table)
item.ids<-fread("http://eve-files.com/chribba/typeid.txt",sep2=" ")
```

Example of the dataset:

```
typeID      typeName
----------- ----------------------------------------
0           #System
2           Corporation
3           Region
4           Constellation
5           Solar System
```

Comment: That looks more like it's fixed width rather than delimted. Look at "iotools" or the "readr" packages. Also, that `#` would be a problem if you don't account for it.

Comment: Or just `read.fwf` in base.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
library(readr)
url = "http://eve-files.com/chribba/typeid.txt"
df = read_fwf(url, fwf_empty(url), skip = 2)
colnames = read_table(url, n_max = 1)
names(df) = names(colnames)
df = na.omit(df)

dim(df)
# [1] 22382     2
summary(df)
 #    typeID         typeName        
 # Min.   :     0   Length:22382      
 # 1st Qu.: 13986   Class :character  
 # Median : 22938   Mode  :character  
 # Mean   : 53827                     
 # 3rd Qu.: 30209                     
 # Max.   :368620
```

Comment: That's what I had in mind with my original comment, but didn't explore further. +1

Comment: Yeah, I was really surprised you didn't go that route in your answer. I tried a little with `read.fwf`, but it gave my issues with row names and it seemed annoying to fix. The `readr` version is much friendlier.

Comment: The base `read.fwf` is painfully slow, so `read_fwf` is actually a very welcome addition to file input options....

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach that uses `extract` from "tidyr" that should be pretty easy to follow.

First, we read the data in, and inspect the first few lines and last few lines. After inspection, we find that the data values are from lines 3 to 22384.

```
x <- readLines("http://eve-files.com/chribba/typeid.txt")
# Check out the data
head(x) # Let's get rid of the first two lines...
tail(x) # ... and the last 3
```

In the extraction stage, we're basically looking for:

- A set of numbers--can be of varying lengths (`([0-9]+)`). It's in `()`, so capture it and extract it to a new column.
- The numbers should be followed by 2 or more spaces (`[ ]{2,}`). That's not in `()`, so we don't need to extract that into a new column.
- The set of spaces can be followed by anything else (`(.*)`). That's in `()`, so capture that and extract it into a new column.

I've also used the first value of "x" to extract the original column names.

Here's what it looks like:

```
library(tidyverse)
data_frame(V1 = x[3:(length(x)-3)]) %>%
  extract(V1, into = scan(text = x[1], what = ""), regex = "([0-9]+)[ ]{2,}(.*)")
# # A tibble: 22,382 x 2
#    typeID           typeName
#  *  <chr>              <chr>
#  1      0            #System
#  2      2        Corporation
#  3      3             Region
#  4      4      Constellation
#  5      5       Solar System
#  6      6    Sun G5 (Yellow)
#  7      7    Sun K7 (Orange)
#  8      8 Sun K5 (Red Giant)
#  9      9      Sun B0 (Blue)
# 10     10     Sun F0 (White)
# # ... with 22,372 more rows
```

Or

```
data_frame(V1 = x[3:(length(x)-3)]) %>%
  separate(V1, into = scan(text = x[1], what = ""), sep = "[ ]{2,}", 
           extra = "merge", convert = TRUE)
```

---

Another approach might be to use `strsplit` with `[ ]{2, }` as the split value. `do.call(rbind, ...)` would be the idiom to follow after that, but you might want to filter only for cases where the split resulted in two values.

```
do.call(rbind, Filter(function(z) length(z) == 2, strsplit(x, "[ ]{2, }")))
```

Answer (score 0):

Read in your text file line-by-line:

```
l <- list()
fileName <- "http://eve-files.com/chribba/typeid.txt"
conn <- file(fileName,open="r")
linn <-readLines(conn)
for (i in 1:length(linn)){
   l[i] <- list(linn[i])
}
close(conn)
```

Create a list of all entries:

```
l_new <- list()
for(p in 1:length(l)) {

    new_vec <- unlist(strsplit(gsub("(?<=[\\s])\\s*|^\\s+|\\s+$", "", l[[p]], perl=TRUE), " "))

    if(!is.na(new_vec[4])) { 
        new_vec_t <- paste(new_vec[2], new_vec[3], new_vec[4])
    } 
    else if (!is.na(new_vec[3])) {
        new_vec_t <- paste(new_vec[2], new_vec[3])
    } 
    else {
        new_vec_t <- paste(new_vec[2])
    }

    l_new[p] <- list(c(new_vec[1], new_vec_t))

}
```

Convert your list to a dataframe:

```
l_new_frame <- data.frame(do.call('rbind', l_new))

l_new_frame <- l_new_frame[-c(1,2),]
names(l_new_frame) <- c('typeID', 'typeName')
```

Check results:

```
print(l_new_frame[1:100,], row.names = FALSE)
```

[image]